# disable "click" for a limited time

Tags: jquery, click, settimeout, disable-link

I made a simple Java Script game where you can flip cards and look for a match. Much resembling "Memory". My problem is when I click the elements (cards) you can still click the other elements (cards) therefore being able to flip more than 2 cards at a time, which would be cheating. I do have in place a setTimeout function that will automatically flip the cards all back over when the time runs out (after 2 cards have been flipped). Is there a way I could disable the clicking of the elements (cards) during the duration of the setTimeout and then re-allow the clicking after.

I tried `$('body').on('click',(false));` cause I figured if you couldn't  click on anything that would work just the same, but it doesn't stop any clicks.

My code runs like this `$("#Card1").on('click', function(){`and each card is in a div (so that way the image is clickable).

Also please excuse any mistakes I've made here, I'm a bit of a novice and new to posting on forms.

Comment: You need to show us more of your code, because your question isn't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$("#Card1").off('click');
```

Comment: So that works, but how would I turn it back on after the setTimeout?